# How to declare an iterator without initializing it? (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, listiterator

I have a `listIterator<String>` called `iit`.

Now I know how to declare it and give it a value, but what if I just want to declare it and initialize it with nothing.

How can it be done?

**EDIT:**
And how can I initialize the iterator with an empty `list<string>`?

Comment: Maybe you could describe the problem you're trying to solve in more detail?

Answer (score 3):

If this variable is a property you can use either `lateinit` or `Delegates.notNull()`.

```
private var lateinit iterator1: ListIterator<String>
private var iterator2: ListIterator<String> by Delegates.notNull()
```

However if it's a local variable you cannot left it uninitialized. You can declare it as a `val` and initialize it later but initialization must happen in all code paths.

```
val iterator: ListIterator<String>
// Do something.
iterator = list.listIterator()
```

Or you can make it nullable, initialize with `null` and later assign it a value.

```
var iterator: ListIterator<String>? = null
// Do something.
iterator = list.listIterator()
```

Comment: And how can I initialize it with an empty list<string>?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: `val iit = listOf<String>().iterator()`

Answer (score 1):

As written as answer, this is what you are asking for.

```
val iit = listOf<String>().iterator()
```

But, from my point of view, create an iterator from an empty list you are not referencing ever again is a bad smell.

Maybe you should consider

```
val l = listOf<String>()
val iit = l.iterator()
```